# mod_proxy for apache/redhat not working

Tags: apache-2.4, redhat, virtualhost, mod-proxy

We have the following scenario:

- First APP: `http://example.com:8090/access/app1`
- Second APP: `http://example.com:8090/access/app2`

We want to configure apache mod_proxy to assign:

- `http://app1.example.com` >> `http://example.com:8090/access/app1`
- `http://app2.example.com` >> `http://example.com:8090/access/app2`

---

We tried the following without success:

```
<VirtualHost app1.example.com:80>
      ServerName app1.example.com
      ProxyPass / http://example.com:8090/access/app1/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com:8090/access/app1/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost app2.example.com:80>
      ServerName app2.example.com
      ProxyPass / http://example.com:8090/access/app2/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com:8090/access/app2/
</VirtualHost>
```

Saved this into `/etc/httpd/conf.d/myconfig.conf`, then restart apache `sudo service http restart`.

When using a browser and writting `http://app1.example.com` the default Apache-Welcome-Page appears, but not our app1 page. Looks like the mod_proxy config is not working.

Setting errorlevel to DEBUG will show the following event in `error_log`:

> [Tue Aug 07 14:18:04.748775 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 1985] [client x.x.x.x:58843] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Typically I use `<VirtualHost *:80>` rather than `<VirtualHost app1.example.com:80>` for name based virtualhosts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your virtual host file as follow

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName app1.example.com
      ProxyPass /app1 http://example.com:8090/access/app1/
      ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://example.com:8090/access/app1/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName app2.example.com
      ProxyPass /app2 http://example.com:8090/access/app2/
      ProxyPassReverse /app2 http://example.com:8090/access/app2/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) comment out or empty the conf.d/welcome.conf file (do not remove it though, or it will get reinstated when you next patch httpd

2) httpd -S is a great friend when considering virtual server issues. This will output where in your configuration your virtualhosts are defined (and which ones are default)

And a bonus: I see you are using port 8090, which makes me think you are possibly dealing with Atlassian products. If you are dealing with Confluence with the Synchrony collaborative editing component, I can perhaps give you some config for the websocket stuff (Atlassian’s documentation is confusing when it comes to reverse proxy configuration )

Comment: Thanks for your time, we proceeded as suggested in point 1 (emptying welcome.conf). Now we don't see the default-welcome-page, but the contets of ` /var/www/html/` folder. That means that our mod_proxy config still not redirecting to our servers. Here is the output for `httpd -S`: https://pastebin.com/GnJgpqtL

Comment: Please put the extra information into your question; it makes it easier for other people to find and solve problems. If app1.example.com and app2.example.com don't resolve to 127.0.0.1, then based on your httpd -S output, your issue will be that you don't have your VirtualHost listening on the interface the request is coming in on. Try `<VirtualHost *:80>` instead.